# Find indexes of duplicated (repeated) numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

I have 2 arrays in which `arr1` stores a number (the salary) and `arr2` stores a string (the employee's name). Since the two arrays are linked, I cannot change the order of `arr1`, or sort it. I am looking for a more efficient way to solve the problem which is to find if there are any duplicates in the array. It might be more than one duplicate, but if no are found it should print *"no duplicates found"*.

```
 int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i<arr_size ;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr_size && i != j; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
              cout << arr2[i] << " " << arr1[i] << endl;
              cout << arr2[j] << " " << arr1[j] << endl;
              count ++;

            }
        }   

    }
    if (count == 0)
    {
        cout << "No employee have same salaries"<<endl;
    }
```

I don't want to use such an inefficient way to solve the problem. Is there any better suggestion? Thanks for the help :)
And the question also requires me to print out all the duplicated employee and salaries pair

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `unordered_set` which has an average constant time insertion and retrieval:

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>
// ...set up arr
int count = 0;
std::unordered_set<int> salaries;
for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i ++) {
    if (salaries.count(arr[i]) > 0) {
        // it's a duplicate
    }
    salaries.insert(arr[i]);
}
// do more stuff
```

Comment: Why this would be more efficient? `unordered_set::count` is log(n), not log(1) [and since it is a set, max count is 1]. Although in this you would check only against non-duplicates, you'd have to create another container and duplicate it in memory, having up to the double of the memory and costing the time to create the copies. This stills a for inside a for.

Comment: `unordered_set::count` is O(1) since it's a hashset, as opposed to `set::count` which is O(log(n)) due to being a red/black search tree set. Also, there is no boolean way to determine if an element is in the hashset, only `count` and `find`. Also, you're not duplicating any containers in memory, and there is no nested loop here.

Comment: Now I understood. Thanks and take my +1

Comment: @Aplet123: you might use result of `insert` instead of `count` to avoid extra look-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time complexity of the algorithm to O(n) by using `unordered_set` on the expense of using additional space.

```cpp
#include<unordered_set>
int main(){
// Initialise your arrays
unordered_set<string> unique;
bool flag = false;
for(int i=0;i<arr_size;i++){
  // Since unordered_set does not support pair out of the box, we will convert the pair to string and use as a key
  string key = to_string(arr1[i]) + arr2[i];
  // Check if key exists in set
  if(unique.find(key)!=unique.end())
    unique.push(key);
  else{
    // mark that duplicate found
    flag = true;
    // Print the duplicate
    cout<<"Duplicate: "+to_string(arr1[i])+"-"+arr2[i]<<endl;
  }
}
if(!flag){
  cout<<"No duplicates found"<<endl;
} else cout<<"Duplicates found"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: but what if i need to print out all the duplicate salaries and its employees?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Haspmap using `unordered_map` and store salaries and index of the salary . 
Now if the same salary exist then increase count